# Logstash is putting old data in Elasticsearch. Can't clean Elasticsearch data

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, purge

I have Logstash reading from a log file `status.log` and sending the output to an Elasticsearch instance.

I want to clean the data in Elasticsearch, for that I'm executing `curl -XDELETE 'http://localhost:9200/index_name/_all'`. If I check through the head plugin, the data is gone.

If that was not enough I'm also cleaning the log file with `echo "" > status.log`.

When I execute the application again, the old data reappears in Elasticsearch but with an updated `@timestamp`. The data is not present again in the `status.log`. The new data is inserted correctly in Elasticsearch.

How can I get rid of the old data? Is it still stored in Elasticsearch or Logstash has some kind of cache?

Comment: Logstash doesn't keep a copy.  Deleting the data from Elasticsearch should be enough.   The only idea that comes to mind is that you have a status.log.00 (etc) and your logstash pattern is matching that file as well.

Answer (score 1):

assuming you are working with the file plugin. If you add the stdout plugin to your output section like so:

```
stdout { codec => rubydebug }
```

logstash will display each processed log element on the console. When using the file plugin every processed logmessage gets a path field telling you were logstash read the message from. maybe that helps you to find out where the messages are coming from...